# How do I fix a "Previous installation hasn't been completed." error in Software Center?

Tags: installation, software-center

Ubuntu Software Center crashes whenever I try to install something. It shows the following error:

> Previous installation hasn't been completed.
>
> The installation could have failed because of an error in the corresponding software package or it was cancelled in an unfriendly way. You have to repair this before you can install or remove any further software.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` from your terminal

Comment: @harish.venkat you beat me to it ;) If `sudo dpkg --configure -a` does not give errors do a `sudo apt-get -f install`. If you do get errors post the error and the results of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` into the question.

Comment: try `synaptics (sudo apt-get install synaptics)` and in `filters` choose `broken` to see any broken packages

Answer (score 1):

Simply install anything through the terminal, such as `ccsm` Using `sudo apt-get install ccsm`. If it fails to install, check its output. It will tell you a recommended solution, or a command to run to fix it. At most times, the command is `sudo dpkg --configure -a` But it varies according to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

you should be able to see which package installation or configuration is causing the holdup.  Purging that application with

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I've received that in the past usually the following gets me back on track.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try removing some of your ppa's from update manager, sometimes if you have installed ppa's through your terminal this also adds them to your update manager and also affects how software centre reacts when too many ppa's are selected, so Ubuntu Software Centre is not broke but can't install programs due to this.  Trust me I reinstalled my OS so many times because of this stupid annoying problem.  Eventually I couldn't even use my Terminal.

Try this open dash type update manager, open it,click -settings, then click other software, then uncheck all the ppa's that you've installed and keep your main ones like "Independent (Source code)[image]

I'd uncheck all the ones below source code.  I could never could figure out this annoying problem until I solved it with this solution.  I really hope this works for you it did for me.  Cheers!