# I've somehow have broken apt - Cannot process updates

Tags: apt

I get this error constantly trying to update or install anything;

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for libgcc1
```

Can anyone assist I've run out of options last chance before I just wipe this thing out and start over?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get check`?

Comment: It comes back without any output.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

Answer (score 1):

I saw this on a system being upgraded from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS. I was able to 'rescue' the system with a combination of the steps below:

You may only need to issue this command to fix it:

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

('#' means from a root prompt, which you get with 'sudo su')

See [How to fix E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266450/how-to-fix-e-internal-error-no-file-name-for-libc6)

But it may be a little more involved than that.

This sequence should help towards reviving the system:

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get install -fy
  (ignore the error at the end)
# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
# dpkg --configure -a
# apt-get install -fy
```

If the 'dpkg -i' command returns with errors, do the 'dpkg --configure -a', but then go back and repeat the 'dpkg -i', but with the 'E' option to speed it up a little:

```
# dpkg -Ei /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```

Eventually, 'apt-get install -fy' should be able to run again, possibly even finish without errors, after which your system should be ok again. Do that cycle 'dpkg -i', 'dpkg --configure', 'apt-get install' a couple of times as long at it keeps making some progress.

See: [1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/945722) and [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/983543)

If the above doesn't work, then this may work:

```
# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*BLA*.deb
```

for 'BLA', replace with the last word of the error message 'E: Internal Error, No file name for BLA'.

If that command says something like 'cannot be configured because WOOPS:MEH is at a different version', then

```
# dpkg --purge --force-all WOOPS:MEH
```

And repeat the 'dpkg -i' command.

After this, go back to the sequence with 'apt-get install -fy' above. You may have to come back to this section for another 'BLA' package, and repeat...

After all this, I would suggest to do an 'apt-get dist-upgrade' again, and/or 'apt-get install ubuntu-desktop', etc to make sure all the needed packages are there.

You may actually finally need to iterate between 'apt-get install -fy' and 'apt-get dist-upgrade' a couple of times before you get a fully working setup again (stop if both commands finish without errors).

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: No love, returns like this;
prrawls@PlexServer:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for prrawls:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libgcc1
prrawls@PlexServer:~$

Comment: What were the latest update applications? cd /var/cache/apt/archives/ then ls , please post the result

Comment: If you know which application cause the problem you can download the file and install it via sudo dpkg -i *.deb then run sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: There is a ton of stuff in that dir.  The output is too big for this comment window. :(.

Comment: I was just doing a normal apt-get Dist-Upgrade and this occurred.  I've prob fuxxed it up more at this point...

Comment: I had a similar problem, sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb  
should fix it.

Comment: Check out this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/235217/how-do-i-fix-a-previous-installation-hasnt-been-completed-error-in-software